# how to change a boolean value if a key is pressed down c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change a Boolean value if a key is pressed down, but when released revert back to false so I can only trigger a if statement if all the arguments a re correct and a key is pressed down.

```
public class boolean
{
    public static Boolean keyPresed = false;
}

private void mainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{                
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" just for debugging ");
        boolean.keyPresed = true;
     } 
      else {
          boolean.keyPressed = false;
         }
        if (tileBuyPlayer2.Checked && ownerShipsPlayer2.peacockOwner == false && boolean.keyPresed == true)
        {
            // do this sorry not on here cause how big it is
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you set keyPresed to true. and check if it's true. this will always be true. why do this? have any places the keyPresed can be set to false?

Comment: Use the KeyUp event to set the flag to false.

Comment: sorry this was just a demonstration version of the code ill change it i have a else statement that puts it back to false

Comment: First you should try to understand how the KeyDown events work (after all, mainForm_KeyDown handles KeyDown events). If you understand this, it will become immediately obvious to you how to make use of the KeyUp event to reset your boolean variable back to false when the "A" key is being released.

Comment: Are you asking me how to set an event handler? See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.110).aspx). I can't see why you even need a global variable to hold the key pressed state here. You could use the KeyPressed event and just check if the pressed key is the desired key, then do your validation.

Comment: how would that be in terms of syntax

Comment: I am using the global variable because i have 40 if statements that do different things. but is there a way i can put it directly on the if statement

Comment: I update my answer, please read it @user3242370

Comment: @user3242370 - You should always include the "@user" in your replies so we know who you are answering.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I am using the global variable because i have 40 if statements that do different things."???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare **keyAPressed** as a `global var in this class`, and `reset` it in your KeyDown event:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public static Boolean keyAPressed = false;

    private void mainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {                
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" just for debugging ");
            keyAPressed = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            keyAPressed = false;
        }
        if (keyAPressed == true)
        {
            // Reset keyAPressed to false
            keyAPressed = false
            if (tileBuyPlayer2.Checked && ownerShipsPlayer2.peacockOwner == false)
            {
                // do this sorry not on here cause how big it is
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or use **KeyUp** event to `reset keyAPressed`:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public static Boolean keyAPressed = false;

    private void mainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {                
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" just for debugging ");
            keyAPressed = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            keyAPressed = false;
        }

        if (tileBuyPlayer2.Checked && ownerShipsPlayer2.peacockOwner == false && keyAPressed == true)
        {
            // do this sorry not on here cause how big it is
        }
    }
    private void mainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keyAPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your comment. I will check my source.

Comment: Please remove the first source code block (it contains an error regarding the second if-statement). The second code block seems to be almost right and contain both the KeyDown + KeyUp handlers. However, KeyDown handler should not set the boolean back to false (what happens if i hold down A and tap on SHIFT?)

Comment: Sorry, but what's the error in the second if-statement? if keyAPressed is true, I will do things. but defore do things, I reset the keyAPressed first.

Comment: i did it like this however it is not showing the message box sould it not show the messagebox

Comment: Did you press a or A?

Comment: Regarding your first source code block: Where do you "do things"? In the "if (tileBuyPlayer2.Checked...)" block? If so, will the code "doing things" ever see keyAPressed being true? What would be the purpose of having keyAPressed? Perhaps i misunderstand your intention...

Comment: ^ There is the link to my code pherahps you can get a better idea. My key press var will be in the varibles class and turned true and false if the user presses a button so that the user can input the information without using the Roll button

Comment: I think you can use KeyCode instead of KeyData. Or use KeyValue: e.KeyValue = 65. This is A. if e.KeyValue = 97. This is a.

Comment: @Chris Shao i pressed both and here is the link to my code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6adchb65mwq9sii/Moneypoly.zip

Comment: Sorry, I can't open this url in my company. But you can debug it, check if the KeyDown event fired. and if the KeyCode is A or other values?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to try Microsoft's reactive framework then you could try doing something like this:

```
var keyDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(mainForm, "KeyDown");

var query =
    from kd in keyDown
    where kd.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.A
    where tileBuyPlayer2.Checked
    where ownerShipsPlayer2.peacockOwner == false
    select kd;

query.Subscribe(x =>
{
    // do your code here
});
```

I might have missed something that you're trying to do, but I think that makes things much easier.